# jqGrid: How to use multiselect on different pages

Tags: jqgrid, paging, multi-select

Simple question, hard to find an answer:

If I try to select a row programmatically, I use this:

```
$('#grid').jqGrid('setSelection', rowId);
```

The problem is that it only selects rows on current visible page. If *rowId* is on another page, it will not be selected.

More info: My goal is to select multiple rows (spread on multiple pages) when page loads for the first time.

Thanks,
Rafael

PS: This guy has the same problem. No answer yet:
[jqgrid multiselect only selects rows on the current page, if paging is enabled. How to make it select rows across pages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710780/jqgrid-multiselect-only-selects-rows-on-the-current-page-if-paging-is-enabled)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Right, jqGrid will only select rows on the current page. In order to select other rows you need to maintain a list of selected ID's and manually select them.

To do this you need to add code to your `loadComplete` event to search the current page and select any of these rows:

```
var ids = grid.jqGrid('getDataIDs');
for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++){
    if (selected[ids[i]] === true ){
        grid.setSelection(ids[i], false);
    }
}
```

You also need to add code to your `onSelectRow` and `onSelectAll` events to adjust the contents of `selected` when the user selects/unselects rows:

```
onSelectRow: function(rowid, status){
    selected[rowid] = status;
    setSelectedDeviceCount();
},

onSelectAll: function(rowids, status){
    for (var i = 0; i < rowids.length; i++){
        selected[rowids[i]] = status;
    }
}
```

Does that help?

Comment: Thanks a lot! Unfortunately the code can't be used this way (my fault, not yours!), but the overall idea made me fix this! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24941828/136219

For a way to achieve what you are looking for.