# selecting all the rows of all the pages of a jqgrid programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid, rows

I want to select all the rows of  all the pages in a jqgrid programatically for a batch update utility. how do i achieve this? I have tried a lot of things but none seem to work. Can anybody point me in the right direction.
My code is as follows:

```
var tot_rows=$("#template-list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
for(var i=1; i<=tot_rows; i++)
{
   $('#template-list').setSelection(tot_rows[i], true);
}
```

Thanks,

Anita

Comment: `I have tried a lot of things` can you update your question with any one try you did?

Comment: ya... i have posted my recent code

Comment: hey why has the question been downvoted? its a perfectly sensible question.

Comment: But i think it will be selecting all the rows in the current page in the pagination. Example, it will select only 10 rows, if you show 10 out of 500+ rows matching the search

Comment: The question may be down voted earlier when the code was not updated.

Comment: ya thats wat.. I want something that will select all the rows i.e 500 as per your example. I have set loadonce =true

Comment: You can set a flag like allRowsSelected=true and send it to the server along with the search criteria, then find all the matched items in server and process further.

Comment: If you set loadonce=true, then you may need to maintain the grid from clientArray

Comment: Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14662632/jqgrid-celledit-in-json-data-shows-url-not-set-alert) i have loaded all the data into client array and set the datatype local and make the grid to play with local data, look into loadcomplete function

Comment: i dint get you. I get the total number of rows in jqgrid in the tot_rows. but i dont understand why the setselection is not getting applied to it? I dont want to select based on any criteria.. i want to select all of it regardless of any criteria.

Comment: Try to check `$('#template-list').setSelection("2", true);` selects row with id=2

Comment: or jQuery('#template-list').jqGrid('setSelection','2');

Comment: ya that is exactly what i have done with setSelection. I will try the clientArray and let you know.

Comment: @murali  no the clientArray thing is not working.. Can you think of something else. I am at my wits end trying to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why i wanted to select all the rows of jqgrid is so that I can get the ids of all of them using selarrrow . But I finally figured out that since thats the  only reason I had wanted to select all of them , I could do that in the following way too

```
var tot_rows=$("#template-list").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
var mydata = $('#template-list').jqGrid('getGridParam','data');
var indexes = $('#template-list').jqGrid('getGridParam', '_index');
for(var i=1; i<=tot_rows; i++)
{
    recId=mydata[indexes[i]].recId;
    //some processing
```

}

And it works!!! Thanks to both of you for your time and help!!!

Comment: thanks this help me alot    As for me                                                                                                                       var tot_rows= grid.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'records');
var gridData =  grid.jqGrid('getGridParam','data');                              for(var i=0; i<tot_rows; i++)
  {
      var subArray = []; 
      var venueID = gridData[i].gridID.toString();                   
             //someprocessing                                                                                    }

Answer (score 3):

First of all it's important to understand that jqGrid supports selection of rows only on **the current page**. The design of jqGrid was done at the time when no local paging of data was supported.

The next problem is that *one can select data only after the data have been loaded* in the grid. For example one can use `loadCompleted` to select some rows.

Selecting of more as one row is possible only if `multiselect: true` option are used. In the case jqGrid automatically adds the column with chechboxes and it adds checkbox in the column header. By checking of the chechbox one can select all rows in the curect page. The Chechbox have `id` which has the prefix `cb_` and follows with the `id` of the grid. For example, it will be `cb_template-list` if the id of the grid is `template-list`. So you can use the following code

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $("#cb_" + this.id).click();
}
```

or, if the id of the grid can contains some special charachters, then better

```
loadComplete: function () {
    $("#cb_" + $.jgrid.jqID(this.id)).click();
}
```

As the result all rows on every page will be selected directly after displaying the page.

**UPDATE:** [Free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) supports `multiPageSelection: true` option, which works in combination with `multiselect: true`. It allows to hold the parameter `selarrrow` *over many pages*. By default jqGrid reset the array `selarrrow` during paging, but in case of usage `multiPageSelection: true, multiselect: true` it doesn't so resetting. Moreover it *preselects* all rows from `selarrrow` array during the building the page. Thus if one fills `selarrrow` array with all rowids of the items (all rows over all pages) then the rows will be displayed selected. The user still can deselect some rows and jqGrid will not change the changes made by the user.

By the way one can fill `selarrrow` array inside of `beforeProcessing` callback if the data are loaded from the server.