# How to move row data from one jqgrid

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am trying to move row from one grid to another grid.I am able to add the row to 2nd Grid but not able to delete row in the 1st grid.

Here is my code:

```
var RowList;
RowList = $('#questions_list').getGridParam('selarrrow');
for (var i=0, list=RowList.length; i<list; i++) 
{
var selectedId = RowList[i];

var selectedData = $('#questions_list').jqGrid('getRowData', selectedId );

$('#selectedQuestions_list').jqGrid('addRowData', selectedId , selectedData );

$('#questions_list').jqGrid('delRowData',selectedId );
}
```

But I am not able to delete row properly,when I add delrowdata,I am not able to add properly.Can any one help me in the code.Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

There is a more comprehensive answer in one of the threads here at stackoverflow which might help you;

[How to delete rows with local data in jqgrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796480/how-to-delete-rows-with-local-data-in-jqgrid)

Answer (score 0):

You should delete the row *after* you saved the data from the row and *before* usage of `addRowData`. The option `rowid` is the value of `id` attribute of the corresponding `<tr>` element which represent the row of the grid. So if you first use `addRowData` with *the same* rowid `selectedId` you will get id duplicates which is not permitted on one HTML/XHTML page. If you swap the lines with calls of `addRowData` and `delRowData` the problem should be solved.

Comment: @user1268130: The goal of stackoverflow is sharing experiences and solutions with other. So it would be fine if you append your question with the part: "SOLUTION"  where you describe the reason of the problem. Another good way would be writing your own answer on your question and "accepting" it (one day later).

Comment: Thanks,sure i will do it. Please check the following question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13451239/how-to-delete-row-and-reload-the-grid-while-adding-a-row-from-one-grid-to-anothe"

Answer (score 0):

As Oleg say that swap the lines with calls of addRowData and delRowData the problem should be solved.It didnt happend when i selected 2 rows and try to move to other grid,it is adding all rows from grid1 and deleting only one row in two selection.

So I have written the code in the following way:

```
var questionids = idsOfSelectedRows;//$('#questions_list').getGridParam('selarrrow');
var questionLength = questionids.length;
for (var i=0; i < questionLength; i++) 
{
 var selectedId = questionids[i];
 var selectedData = $('#questions_list').jqGrid('getLocalRow', selectedId);
 $('#selectedQuestions_list').jqGrid('addRowData', selectedId, selectedData);
 $('#selectedQuestions_list').trigger("reloadGrid");
}

for (var i = 0; i < questionLength ; i++) { 
 var selectedId = questionids[i];
 console.log("delete is "+ $('#questions_list').jqGrid('delRowData', selectedId));
 //$('#questions_list').trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

To get idsOfSelectedRows see the [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithPermanentMultiselect3.htm) and you can see the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710780/jqgrid-multiselect-only-selects-rows-on-the-current-page-if-paging-is-enabled)  too