# How to delete row and reload the grid while adding a row from one grid to another

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using multiselect in my jqgrid. I am implementing adding row from 1st jqgrid to 2nd jqgrid,at the same time I am removing same row from 1st grid which I have been selected

By using the [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/SimpleLocalGridWithPermanentMultiselect3.htm) I make use of permanent multiselect concept.

By using that concept I am able to select row even in other pages and I am able to copy it.

**My problem starts from here:**

I have 6 records in 1st grid and my row number is 5. So I will have have two pages with 5 rows in 1 page and 6th row in 2nd page.

When I select the a row in page1 and 6th row in page2 and able to move to data from 1st jqgrid to 2nd jqgrid and at the same time I need to delete data in 1st jqgrid.As I was in 2nd page while deleting data,6th row will be deleted and its not showing the page 1 even though I have use the trigger("reloadGrid");

Here is the code which I use for adding and deleting row from 1st jqgrid to 2nd jqgrid

```
var questionids = idsOfSelectedRows;
var questionLength = questionids.length;
for (var i=0; i < questionLength; i++) 
{
 var selectedId = questionids[i];
 var selectedData = $('#questions_list').jqGrid('getLocalRow', selectedId);
 $('#selectedQuestions_list').jqGrid('addRowData', selectedId, selectedData);
 $('#selectedQuestions_list').trigger("reloadGrid");
}

for (var i = 0; i < questionLength ; i++) { 
 var selectedId = questionids[i];
 console.log("delete is "+ $('#questions_list').jqGrid('delRowData', selectedId));
 //$('#questions_list').trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

Please can anyone help in the code,Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Where you get `idsOfSelectedRows`? I suppose that you used `getDataIDs` to get all ids of rows **of the current page**. If you use *local* grid or grid with `loadonce: true` the internal parameters `data` and `_index` will be filled by jqGrid. You can use `for-in` loop to enumerate all properties of `_index`. In the way you will get ids **of all rows over all pages** of the grid.

Moreover, if you add *multiple* rows you should not call `reloadGrid` after adding of every row. It reduce performance in multiple times. Instead of that you can manipulate manually `_index` and `data` of destination grid and then call `reloadGrid` once.

More then that I explained you in [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13444813/315935) on your previous question that you should write the code so that it produce **no id duplicates**. You current code have definitively id duplicates. The row with id `selectedId` exist in the source grid. If you use `.jqGrid('addRowData', selectedId, selectedData);` the row **with the same id `selectedId`** will be added to the next grid. So you will have two `<tr>` element on the page with the same id. If you will use `.jqGrid('delRowData', selectedId))` it could delete the rows from *another grid*. In general the working with the page having id duplicates can produce unpredictable results. Different web browsers can produce different results.

If you not sure whether you have or not have id dupplicate problem you should use `idPrefix` option with different values in all grids which you use.