# Get jQgrid selected rows

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using multi select jqgrid.
I have a *jqgrid* with 1500 rows. The result is paged and on one page I am displaying 100 entries.

I need to get all rows selected in other pages also.

I am using

`$("#tableNm").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');`

But it is giving only current page selected rows..

Can any one help me?

Comment: is it `json` or `local type` jqGrid?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of this questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710780/jqgrid-multiselect-only-selects-rows-on-the-current-page-if-paging-is-enabled  and also this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11567915/jqgrid-how-to-use-multiselect-on-different-pages

Comment: @jeffery_the_wind mark it as duplicate

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the other questions linked by Jeffery, jqGrid only maintains selection on the current page. You need to write your own application-level code to maintain the selected rows across the other pages.

Answer (score 0):

Just for some tips to begin with -

```
onSelectRow: function(){
   //remember which rows were selected/de-selected, 
   //via cookies, HTML5 localStorage, etc
}


loadComplete : function(){
   //fetch which rows were previously selected and highlight them if they are 
   // present in the current page
}
```