# free jqGrid - search filter and select all

Tags: javascript, jquery, free-jqgrid

I'm using free jqGrid. I want the ability to apply a search filter on a table and then use the select all functionality to then select the rows in the filtered results. Then if the filter is cleared, to still have the rows selected.

This needs to work across the paging functionality also.

I've followed the answer in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18502592/make-jqgrid-multiselect-selection-persist-following-pagination-toolbar-search) and this unfortunately doesn't give the desired behaviour as the "select all" is only selecting the row on the current page in view.

I need for the "selarrrow" to be populated with the rows selected but this feature stops working if I remove multiPageSelection: true.

How can I achieve the above please?

This is the code that I have so far:

```
$(function () {

    var selectedRows = {};

    $("#packageResults").jqGrid({
        url: '@Url.Action("GetPackages", "Package", new { id = ViewBag.ProductOfferingId })',
        datatype: "json",
        colNames: ['Id', 'Name', 'Description'],
        colModel: [
            { name: 'id', key: true, width: 55, sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'name', width: 300, searchoptions: { "sopt": ["bw", "eq"] } },
            { name: 'description', width: 90 }                
        ],
        rowNum: 25,
        rowList: [25, 50],
        pager: true,
        toppager: true,
        sortname: 'id',
        viewrecords: true,
        guiStyle: "bootstrap",
        search: true,
        //height: "auto",
        multiPageSelection: true,
        multiselect: true,
        caption: "Packages",
        loadonce: true,
        jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
        onSelectRow: function (rowId, status, e) {

            if (status === false) {
                delete selectedRows[rowId];
            } else {
                selectedRows[rowId] = status;
            }

        },
        onSelectAll: function (rowIds, status) {

            //apply select all to only those items in filter/search
            if (status === true) {
                for (var i = 0; i < rowIds.length; i++) {
                    selectedRows[rowIds[i]] = true;
                }
            } else {
                for (var i = 0; i < rowIds.length; i++) {
                    delete selectedRows[rowIds[i]];
                }
            }
        },
        gridComplete: function () {
            for (var rowId in selectedRows) {
                $("#packageResults").setSelection(rowId, true);
            }
        }
    });
    $("#packageResults").jqGrid('navGrid',
        { edit: false, add: false, del: false, search: true, view: false, refresh: true },
        {}, {}, {}, { multipleSearch: true, multipleGroup: true, showQuery: true });
    $("#packageResults").jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false, defaultSearch: "cn" });


});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear where you apply some **filter** after loading of the grid. Where you get the filter (it's static, you load it from the server, from `localStorage`, ...). You should use `forceClientSorting: true` option, which allows to sort *and to filter* the data loaded from the server. See [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/formEditOnDoubleClick-jqueryui-fa-bootstrap.htm) which uses `postData.filters` to apply the filter and [another one](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/OK/filterByAdditionalPropertiesAndSearchingDialog1.htm), which uses `additionalProperties` additionally.

Comment: The behavior of `onSelectAll` isn't clear for me. One you fill `selarrrow` with required values then the rows will be *automatically selected* on changing the page (because of `multiPageSelection: true`). The `selarrrow` array will be replacement of `selectedRows`. If all visible (from the current page) rows from `selarrrow`/`selectedRows` are *already selected* then you don't need to do anything inside of `onSelectAll` or `onSelectRow`. I'm not sure which behavior exactly you want to implement.

Comment: @Oleg The user is responsible for applying the filters after the grid has loaded. The expected behaviour is, the grid loads, a user applies the filters to the grid, the user clicks "select all" option, this should only select the filtered data. The actual behaviour is that is that when the user clicks "select all", all rows of data are selected. How do I achieve the expected behaviour please?

Comment: @Oleg I've created a demo using one of your previous demo's which hopefully illustrate my issue - https://jsfiddle.net/ja2awqgL/. Under the "Shipped via" column, if you filter by "FedEx", you should have 7 results over 2 pages. If you then use the multiselect / select all option, this will select ALL rows but I only want to select the 7 rows from filtered results. Then if I remove the filter and apply a different filter, I want the 7 rows to be selected plus any others I select. Hope this clarifies things. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The solution could be about the following

```
multiPageSelection: true, 
multiselect: true,
onSelectAll: function (rowIds, selected) {
    var p = $(this).jqGrid("getGridParam"), id, i,
        filteredIds = p.search ?
            $.map(p.lastSelectedData, function (item) {
                return item[p.localReader.id];
            }) :
            [];

    if (selected && filteredIds.length > 0) {
        for (id in p._index) { // enumerate all rowids
            if ($.inArray(id, filteredIds) < 0) {
                // remove non-filtered rowids from p.selarrrow
                i = $.inArray(id, p.selarrrow);
                if (i >= 0) {
                    p.selarrrow.splice(i, 1);
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ja2awqgL/4/.

Comment: Hi @Oleg - sorry for the late reply. Thank you for coming back to me. This appears to do some of what I want, however I want to keep adding to `p.selarrrow` when the user changes the filter criteria and clicks "select all".

Comment: @jgill09: You are welcome! I still don't understand which custom behavior you want to implement. The demo https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ja2awqgL/4/, which I posted set selected (in `p.selarrrow`) all filtered rows on "select all" click. `p.selarrrow` will be automatically modified by selection. If you want to change `p.selarrrow` when the user apply new filter of clear the filter you can define `beforeSearch` or `beforeClear` callbacks (see [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:toolbar_searching)). You can modify `p.selarrrow` inside of the callbacks.

Comment: @jgill09: The test case on my demo is the following: 1) set the filter `"yes"` in the "Close" column, 2) click "select all" - the filtered rows will be selected, 3) change the filter `"any"` in the "Close" column to see all the row. You will see that the previously selected rows (by the filter at the moment of clicking "select all") stay selected.

Comment: The test case I'm after is 1) set the filter `"Fedex"` on the "Shipped via" column 2) click "select all" 3) change the filter to `"TNT"` on the "Shipped via" column 4) click "select all" 5) set the filter `"any"` on "Shipped via" column. I should see all of the `"Fedex"` and `"TNT"` rows selected. Hope that clarifies things. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @jgill09: Sorry, but you want implement **very exotic** behavior. Do you think about **uncelect all** behavior? Let us you open any demo and click on "select all" button (which is not correct name). The first click means really "select all", but the second one is "unselect all". How the button should work in your case?

Comment: It's a good question. So in the test case I've mentioned above, after number 5, the "select all" will not be ticked because after the user has cleared the filter criteria, they should see all rows and only `"Fedex"` and `"TNT"` rows should be ticked and therefore the select all should be be unticked. If the user then decides to click "select all" then all rows should be ticked and if they untick "select all" then they've cleared all the previous rows selected/ticked.

Comment: @jgill09: In any way you can introduce your *custom* option, for example `lastSelRowids`, which will be hold the previously selected rows. See https://jsfiddle.net/OlegKi/ja2awqgL/5/, where I use `.slice(0)` to *clone* the array. Holding `lastSelRowids` you can implement any your custom behavior inside of `onSelectAll`. You can combine (concatenate) the current selection from my answer with the array `lastSelRowids` and to save the result in `selarrrow` *and* in `lastSelRowids`. In the way you can implement any your custom selection or unselection.